# How to populate Drop Downd list with session data in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

i want to populate combo box with the session data ex:Name of user in the .ctp file,how to that .please explain me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given all the other questions, you have posed over the last couple of hours, I can really recommend, to do the 15 minutes blog tutorial on the cakephp site.

If you have the bare system already completed, go back and look deeper into it, you will find that there are combo boxes being automatically populated. You should be able to modify the code to your needs.

Maybe the `Controller::set()` method, which can set view variables from the controller, can come in handy.

If you follow this approach, many of your future questions will be answered.